# what are disadvantages of having two PeerConnections for one call?

Tags: webrtc

I am thinking of changing my application from using a single PeerConnection for transferring media both ways to one PeerConnection for upstream and one for downstream for a single call between two peer.

The advantages I foresee:

- Less worry about signalling state of PeerConnection when changing offering media from `video+audio` to `audio` and vice-versa
- Might be easier to plug an Media Servers like `kurento` into the application ( in case of multi user call, lesser upload bandwidth required by user).
- (not sure of this one) single responsibility principle, each PeerConnection has single role.

the major reason I want to do this change is, I am noticing that if peer(peer1) offers only `audio` but other peer(peer2) answers with both `video+audio`,  peer1 recieves only the audio for some reason, but if peer1 had been an answerer, it is able to recieve both MediaTracks without any problem. Not sure if it is a bug in my app or browser( got same result in firefox and chrome). I was able to make a workaround by maintaining states, changing offerer based on state and stuff, but having problems with both peers changing state (nearly) simultaneously. Thought above proposal would be simpler solution and I can get rid of maintaining states.

Other than the obvious disadvantages of extra overhead of more ICE candidate requests( n STUN n TURN), maintaining extra PeerConnections, any other issue possible following this design?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing prevents you from doing that, but I suspect there's a simpler solution to your problem which you kind of buried:

> the major reason I want to do this change is, I am noticing that if peer(peer1) offers only audio but other peer(peer2) answers with both video+audio, peer1 recieves only the audio for some reason,

Don't ask me why, but the default spec behavior when peer1 only offers audio, is to only request audio from the other side. To override this and leave yourself open to receiving video as well if the other side has it, use [RTCOfferOptions](http://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#idl-def-RTCOfferOptions):

```
peer1.createOffer({ offerToReceiveVideo: true }).then( ... )
```

(or if you're using the legacy non-promise API it's the third argument.)

The nice thing with this is that it is intent-based so you don't need to track any state. e.g. always using `{ offerToReceiveVideo: true, offerToReceiveAudio: true }` may be right for you.

Comment: I'll note that some systems purposely use two (or more) one-way connections, like TokBox.  It makes some things easier, as you mention, and some things harder (more state to synchronize, setup time, etc)

Answer (score 1):

A resource issue would be that you are be utilizing more ports as both sides of the connection have to complete the DTLS handshake(which is done peer-to-peer and not through the signalling server).

A design challenge is keeping track of two connections orthogonally. It could be hairy and will more readily show errors in the underlying webrtc implementation if the state is not handled properly(browser state errors, etc.).

Comment: I thought, since the extra issue is on the browser, it should not cost that much, also thought it would be better for old browsers that does not support re-negotiation, like when you change stream, at least your screen keep receiving his stream, while you close and share your stream again, at least it would appear seamless on one side.

Comment: @mido22, for sure. That is where orthogonality really shines in this solution. I just know that the webrtc state in the browser(at least in the past) could be rather fragile in certain situations. It has grown more robust over the past year or so and hopefully should not pose any serious issues to your solution.