# Where do those WebRTC Adapter.js states come from?

Tags: google-chrome, webrtc

I stumbled upon the following errors while debugging my WebRTC app and I cannot figure out what they mean:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Failed to set remote answer sdp: Called in wrong state: STATE_INPROGRESS
```

and

```
Uncaught (in promise) Failed to set remote answer sdp: Called in wrong state: STATE_INIT
```

Which state is it that's supposed to be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are getting this error because you are trying to set the SDP answer in the wrong state. Take a look at [this document](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-webrtc/2012Sep/att-0097/WebRTCstatesandcallbacks.pdf). It should clarify things for you. State diagram (taken from that document):

[image: State Diagram]

Comment: Maybe, but where do STATE_INIT and STATE_INPROGRESS come from then?

Comment: @nexus, been a while since I faced this issue, but take a look at jib's answer to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29534460/webrtc-simultaneous-renegotiation-issue), I think STATE_INIT is same as RTCPeerConnection "new" state n the other, not sure, probably "active" state

Comment: Sounds right. The STATE_* names are Chrome artifacts. You could try it in another browser and see what it says.