# unable to set local description while handling race condition because of simultaneous offer exchange

Tags: webrtc, race-condition

I am looking for a solution where a peer sends an offer and if for some reason (may be due to network failure or the other peer is not yet started) it should rollback to stable state (with local & remote sdp set to null) so that it can handle subsequent offer messages from other peers.

Can anyone explain how to go about this?

Comment: I followed below approach to handle above situation.

Comment: i handled it by controlling the offer and answer exchange by using a binary semaphore kind of mechanism at the signaling server. But, I am facing another problem now. I am not able to send video stream to the remote peer. video transmission is happening on only one direction. i am using a single peer connection object.

Answer (score 2):

I just faced the same issue, and I found that this problem has a name: it's called "glare".

This person answered a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29552565/1690115

But there are better solutions, based on random tokens. The idea is that peers always add a random number along their offer. When peer A and peer B notice the collision (because they each receive an offer while they have an outstanding offer), the one with the biggest token wins.

I'm not an expert on WebRCT and glare, but I hope this helped a little bit. You can find many solutions on google by searching "webrtc glare".